# xrandr --addmode gives me error xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed

Tags: xrandr

I have a monitor that will not do resolutions that it handles fine on windows on ubuntu, my monitor can do 1600x1200 at 75 hertz but when I try to add it as a mode using `xrandr --addmode` it gives me the error `xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed` can anyone help?